# PHP: Write to file only after the variable contains data from the XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm very new to PHP. I'm trying to:

1. write the data from an XML file into a variable;
2. write the data from the variable into the file;

The file is empty. I think it has to do with the delay during XML file parsing. Variable is created, but it is empty and that's why the file is empty. Is there a delay or some sort of workaround for this?

The code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("someXMLFileWhichTakesTimeToLoad.xml") or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
$myfile = fopen("eeFuelPrice.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
print_r($xml);
fwrite($myfile, $xml);
print_r("successfully wrote file");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to work with the XML as XML, rather than a string ...

Note: `simplexml_load_file()` is a blocking function: when it returns, the file has parsed.

You need some error handling: you're printing `$xml` so I assume that prints the data you're expecting. `fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written -- what does it return? If it's zero, (which it probably will be) then this is your issue.

You could instead use something like [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) to print your XML object to a file. `fwrite()` is for writing bytes (strings) to file.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` functions.

```
$xml = "someXMLFileWhichTakesTimeToLoad.xml";
$myfile = "eeFuelPrice.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($xml);
file_put_contents($myfile, $content);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it would be enough for me to just get file contents, save them and then handle them with JS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: too soon, too fast: I get this error: Warning: file_get_contents( ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 21

Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in index.php on line 22 Maybe this is due to the file being on another server?

Comment: your script and xml file must same directroy if you use code above. If you try to write xml file of another server, you declare the $xml variable to link to xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are getting is that simplexml_load_file returns an object ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)) You can't write an object directly to a file using fwrite:

> int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )

If all you are trying to do is take the contents of one XML file and add it to a text file, then just read the contents with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead; it returns a string value instead of an object.